# How to trigger handleSubmit on the callback in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to wait for the callback before pushing place_id to BrowserHistory

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    browserHistory.push(`/place_id/`+this.state.place.place_id);
}
```

The form submits automatically when a place is selected (which is good) but this.state.place is still null until the callback.

```
<form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit.bind(this) }>
    <Autocomplete
        onPlaceSelected={(place) => {
            this.setState({place: place});
        }}
    />
</form>
```

Comment: haha I am handling the state change within the onPlaceSelected callback just like the answer says. I'll keep researching! Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  if (this.state.place) {
    browserHistory.push(`/place_id/`+this.state.place.place_id);
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

And this is the component:

```
  <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit.bind(this) } ref={(c) => this.frm = c}>
    <Autocomplete
        onPlaceSelected={(place) => {
          this.setState({place: place}, () => {this.frm.submit()});
        }}
    />
  </form>
```

The callback of the `setState` method will call the `submit` of the form **after** the value of the place was set into the state, and once it's there - the `browserHistory.push` will be called inside the `handleSubmit` because you have a place inside `this.state`.

Answer (score 2):

what you could do is trigger the update once the state is modified, using a callback:

```
this.setState({place: place}, () => browserHistory.push(`/place_id/`+this.state.place.place_id));
```

You can see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) that `setState` is not guaranteed to be run immediately.

Comment: Perfect answer this.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply

```
changeRoute(place) {
  browserHistory.push(`/place_id/`+place.place_id);
}
```

then

```
  <form ref={(c) => this.frm = c}>
    <Autocomplete onPlaceSelected={this.changeRoute} />
  </form>
```